# Why is cat /proc/[pid]/pagemap not giving any output?

Tags: linux-kernel, proc

When I use the command `cat /proc/<pid>/pagemap`, I'm not getting any output. Usually I get some binary output but now I am not getting anything at first.

The output starts coming an hour or so after entering the command `cat /proc/<pid>/pagemap`. I have tried different kernel versions bu the problem still exists.

Comment: With kernel processes you don't get output usualls. With user processes try hexdump /proc/pid/pagemap, should show something (zero bytes). Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369185/viewing-pagetable-for-a-process

Comment: Related - https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt.

Answer (score 3):

`/proc/[pid]/pagemap` is a virtual file with 2<sup>25</sup>, 64-bit wide entries for pages. For a given program most of the entries will be 0x00000000. There are two problems to your approch of `cat /proc/[pid]/pagemap`:

- To print such a file would take an enormous amount of time.
- The file consists of entries which are not ASCII Printable chars.

We can solve the above problems by:

- Use `/proc/[pid]/maps` to get the virtual address and seek to position on `pagemap` file.
- Use hexdump instead of cat to print the entry.

You may refer to [Viewing pagetable for a process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369185/viewing-pagetable-for-a-process) for more detailed research regarding same.

Comment: probably a typo: 2^52, not 2^25.